# Importing/accessing dictionaries as class variables in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, module

I have a dictionary from an imported module assigned to a class variable. I try to print the variable straight from the instance, it gives me the whole dictionary (good). But when I try to get a value from a key in said dictionary, I receive a name error.

Here's my main code:

```
import list_module

class Calculator(object):
    tile_chart = list_module.tile_sizes

    def __init__(self, dims_string):
        self.dims_string = dims_string
        self.grout_choice_input = input('Input grout thickness.\n>')
        self.grout_choice = self.grout_choice_input.strip('\"')

    def main(self):
        if self.dims_string in tile_chart:
            self.my_tile_size = tile_chart.get('dims_string')
            self.grout_line_index = self.grout_lines.index(self.grout_choice)
            return self.my_tile_size[self.grout_line_index]
        else:
            print("not configured yet")

calculator_instance = Calculator(table_str)
print(Calculator.tile_chart)
print(calculator_instance.tile_chart)
calculator_instance.main()
```

Here's the code I'm importing, called list_module.py :

```
tile_sizes = { 
         '1x1' : [90,45,29,22,14,10,7,5],
         '2x2' : [186,93,61,45,29,22,17,10],
         '3x3' : [284,142,93,69,45,33,26,15],
         '4.25x4.25' : [404,202,134,99,65,48,38,25],
         '4x8' : [254,127,84,63,42,31,25,15],
         '6x6x1/4' : [570,285,190,142,93,69,55,35],
         '6x6x1/2' : [286,143,95,71,47,35,28,15],
         '8x8' : [510,255,169,126,84,62,50,30],
         '12x12' : [766,383,253,191,126,94,75,45],
         '13x13' : [830,415,275,207,137,102,82,50],
         '16x16' : [1020,510,340,255,169,126,101,60],
         '18x18' : [1150,575,383,288,191,142,114,70],
         '20x20' : [1280,640,452,320,212,159,126,75],
         '24x24' : [1536,768,510,383,255,191,152,95]
         }

grout_lines = ["1/16","1/8","3/16","1/4","3/8","1/8","5/8","1"]
```

Here's the printout:

```
{'1x1': [90, 45, 29, 22, 14, 10, 7, 5], '2x2': [186, 93, 61, 45, 29, 22, 17, 10], '3x3': [284, 142, 93, 69, 45, 33, 26, 15], '4.25x4.25': [404, 202, 134, 99, 65, 48, 38, 25], '4x8': [254, 127, 84, 63, 42, 31, 25, 15], '6x6x1/4': [570, 285, 190, 142, 93, 69, 55, 35], '6x6x1/2': [286, 143, 95, 71, 47, 35, 28, 15], '8x8': [510, 255, 169, 126, 84, 62, 50, 30], '12x12': [766, 383, 253, 191, 126, 94, 75, 45], '13x13': [830, 415, 275, 207, 137, 102, 82, 50], '16x16': [1020, 510, 340, 255, 169, 126, 101, 60], '18x18': [1150, 575, 383, 288, 191, 142, 114, 70], '20x20': [1280, 640, 452, 320, 212, 159, 126, 75], '24x24': [1536, 768, 510, 383, 255, 191, 152, 95]}
{'1x1': [90, 45, 29, 22, 14, 10, 7, 5], '2x2': [186, 93, 61, 45, 29, 22, 17, 10], '3x3': [284, 142, 93, 69, 45, 33, 26, 15], '4.25x4.25': [404, 202, 134, 99, 65, 48, 38, 25], '4x8': [254, 127, 84, 63, 42, 31, 25, 15], '6x6x1/4': [570, 285, 190, 142, 93, 69, 55, 35], '6x6x1/2': [286, 143, 95, 71, 47, 35, 28, 15], '8x8': [510, 255, 169, 126, 84, 62, 50, 30], '12x12': [766, 383, 253, 191, 126, 94, 75, 45], '13x13': [830, 415, 275, 207, 137, 102, 82, 50], '16x16': [1020, 510, 340, 255, 169, 126, 101, 60], '18x18': [1150, 575, 383, 288, 191, 142, 114, 70], '20x20': [1280, 640, 452, 320, 212, 159, 126, 75], '24x24': [1536, 768, 510, 383, 255, 191, 152, 95]}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ultracolor_calc_oop.py", line 68, in <module>
    calculator_instance.main()
  File "ultracolor_calc_oop.py", line 53, in main
    if self.dims_string in tile_chart:
NameError: name 'tile_chart' is not defined
```

As you can see, the dictionary `tile_chart` is printing perfectly when called on a class and instance level. Maybe I have a fundamental misunderstanding on what constitutes 'definition', but to me, printability implies that it's defined. Yet as soon as I run `main()`, I get a name error saying that it's *not* defined.

Any guidance?

Comment: Note, a class having a `main` method is not a typical Python pattern. Usually, `main` would be a module-level function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your method references within `main()` from `tile_chart` to `self.tile_chart`.

You have defined the variable at class rather than method level. Therefore, to call the variable you have to refer to `self`.

Comment: I really thought I had tried that, but I guess not, because your solution works. If I defined it at a method level, what would that change?

Comment: You can also use `Calculator.title_chart`

Answer (score 0):

Use self.tile_chart instead of tile_chart in your main function. All the object elements will be referenced using self.

```
import list_module

class Calculator(object):
    tile_chart = list_module.tile_sizes

    def __init__(self, dims_string):
        self.dims_string = dims_string
        self.grout_choice_input = input('Input grout thickness.\n>')
        self.grout_choice = self.grout_choice_input.strip('\"')

    def main(self):
        if self.dims_string in self.tile_chart:
            self.my_tile_size = self.tile_chart.get('dims_string')
            self.grout_line_index = self.grout_lines.index(self.grout_choice)
            return self.my_tile_size[self.grout_line_index]
        else:
            print("not configured yet")

calculator_instance = Calculator(table_str)
print(Calculator.tile_chart)
print(calculator_instance.tile_chart)
calculator_instance.main()
```

Answer (score 0):

> You have defined the variable at class rather than method level.
>   Therefore, to call the variable you have to refer to self

Yes, that works on reads, because you access via the instance, which
hasn't an attribute by that name, so the search goes up to the class, which has the attribute. And works also with in-place writes (writing into the inside of some compound var such as dict or list). But not when assigning a new object to the name.

That is, be aware that you can change the class variable in-place, using the `self` qualifier, but if you assign another object to the class variable, using the `self` qualifier, that will create a new instance variable by that name, disconnected from the class variable. If that is a true class variable, shared by all instances, use `Calculator.tile_chart`, not `self.tile_chart`, to be on the safe side for reads and writes.